# Play music in the background using AVAudioplayer

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ipad, avaudioplayer

I want to play music  even if the app goes in background. I checked all stackoverflow links but none of them worked. Please help need to do it today.

I had used following code:-

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Day At The Beach"  ofType: @"mp3"];

NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: soundFilePath];

NSError *error;
playerTemp = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:&error];
playerTemp.numberOfLoops = 0;
AudioSessionSetActive(true);
[playerTemp play];
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I had solved this question by referring [iOS Application Background tasks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

and make some changes in `.plist` file of our application..

**Update**

write this code in your controller's view did load method like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"in-the-storm" ofType:@"mp3"]];
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [audioPlayer play];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: i did this but when i press home button the music stops playing.

Comment: On which device you are using this testing

Comment: You should test this on those devices which supports background task

Comment: do not test this in simulator. Test it on actual iphone / iPad

Comment: Note that the sound can be played somewhere other than the viewDidLoad method, but the three lines for setting up the AVAudioSession must be left in the viewDidLoad method, not bundled with the sound playback code.

Comment: beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents solves playing sound in background, but what if I would like to hide/disable remote controls. I am playing a beep-sound and I don't want remote controls (play,stop,etc) to flash on the screen when device is locked

Comment: In my case,background audio is play but thumnail does't show.

Answer (score 34):

I just wanted to add a note to Mehul's answer.  This line:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

is actually very important.  I used other tutorials to get my AVAudioPlayer up and running.  Everything worked fine except my audio would not START if the app was in the background.  To clarify, my audio was fine if it was already playing when the app went into the background...but it would not start if the app was already in the background.

Adding the above line of code made it so my audio would start even if the app was in the background.

Comment: Say might either of you (@Anurag) know why that is so important?  It worked for me too, after hours of searching.  Crazy how it's not mentioned in any of the Audio Programming Guide (AVFoundation, AudioQueue or AudioSession).

Comment: +1 Brilliant! I just asked at http://stackoverflow.com/q/13335940/13441 and have no obtain any answers. Just looks ugly for my app that remove control buttons attached to it.

Answer (score 6):

You need to set 'audio' as one of your UIBackgroundModes in Info.plist. Apple has [documentation on the issue](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW24).

Comment: i did this but when i press home button the music stops playing.

Comment: The link has been fixed.

Comment: Link is dead (*"Sorry, that page cannot be found"*).

Comment: [New link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionBasics/AudioSessionBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH3-SW3)
This is what needs to be done essentially. All the "remote" thingy is secondary if you're not using those functions.

Answer (score 6):

Write this line in to plist for background run...

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
      <array>
              <string>audio</string>
      </array>
```

Write this code Where you want to use

```
AVAudioPlayer*  audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:self.urlForConevW error:&error];
audioPlayer.delegate = self;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops =  1;       
[audioPlayer play];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use MPMoviePlayerController even to play solo-audio movies. If you like it, read this detailed Apple Library Technical Q&A:

[iOS Developer Library Technical Q&A QA1668](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1668/_index.html)

Answer (score 3):

Also important here if you are using `MPMusicPlayerController`:
You must use:

```
[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer]
```

And Not

```
[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer]
```

Also if you don't want your app to `stop music` which was playing when your app is started, look here:
[AVAudioPlayer turns off iPod - how to work around?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507541/avaudioplayer-turns-off-ipod-how-to-work-around)

Answer (score 3):

**Step1**

Make the following changes in info.plist

1. Application does not run in background : NO
2. Required background modes

   `item0 :App plays audio or streams audio/video using AirPlay`

**Step 2**
Don't forget to add the following things in `MainViewController.h` file

1. `#import <'AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>`
2. `@interface MainViewController:<'AVAudioPlayerDelegate>`
3. `AVAudioPlayer *H_audio_player;`

**Step 3**
Add the following code inside the **play action** of your `MainViewController` class.

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-%d",C_CID, C_SID] ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
H_audio_player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
H_audio_player.delegate = self;
H_audio_player.numberOfLoops = -1;
```

Answer (score 2):

If even after setting audio as one of your  `UIBackgroundModes` in the plist the audio stops when going to background, try `setting` your `application's audio session` to `media playback`.

Here's the related reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Here's about what the code's gonna look like:

```
NSError *activationError = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &activationError];

NSError*setCategoryError = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &setCategoryError];
```

Comment: If you don't want your app to stop whatever audio is playing when your app is started, you need to do one more thing - look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507541/avaudioplayer-turns-off-ipod-how-to-work-around

Answer (score 2):

I use the below code. It work for me, and call on the button click of audio player instance  method.

```
NSError *error; NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"music" ofType:@"mp3"]]; 
self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&error];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error: &error]; 
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
[self.player prepareToPlay];
```

Answer (score 2):

From all answers is missing this code to control the player when user is waking the device:

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
        return YES;
    }

- (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    switch (event.subtype) {

        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay:

            [_audioPlayer play];
            break;

        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause:

            [_audioPlayer pause];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

And you have all these options:

```
UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay                 = 100,
UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause                = 101,
UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlStop                 = 102,
UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause      = 103,
UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlNextTrack            = 104,
UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPreviousTrack        = 105,
UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlBeginSeekingBackward = 106,
UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlEndSeekingBackward   = 107,
UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlBeginSeekingForward  = 108,
UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlEndSeekingForward    = 109,
```

Answer (score 1):

**To play your audio in background**

Step 1 :Just add in your *info.plist*make an array 
[image]

step2 :

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier task = 0;
    task=[application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        NSLog(@"Expiration handler called %f",[application backgroundTimeRemaining]);
        [application endBackgroundTask:task];
        task=UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];
}
```

step3 :

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iNamokar" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

    AVAudioPlayer *newPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
[player prepareToPlay];
[self.player play];
```

Comment: I have a few questions:
What is the idea behind "Step 2"?
I this line mandatory 
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents] in "Step 3"?

Answer (score 0):

From Apple's sample code: Audio Mixer (MixerHost)

```
// If using a nonmixable audio session category, as this app does, you must activate reception of 
//    remote-control events to allow reactivation of the audio session when running in the background.
//    Also, to receive remote-control events, the app must be eligible to become the first responder.
- (void) viewDidAppear: (BOOL) animated {

    [super viewDidAppear: animated];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

I think remote control events are not needed for the following case:

```
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers,
                        sizeof(value), &value);
```