# audio playing when app goes to background

Tags: iphone, audio, avaudioplayer

I would like to play a sound when someone click home button of iphone/ipad, e.g. when application goes in background.

I have already added "App plays audio" required background in my info.plist.

I am trying to play an audio file in applicationWillResignActive and applicationDidEnterBackground methods using AVAudioPlayer. But no success yet.

Any solution to this?

Comment: same question like this:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619794/play-music-in-background-in-iphone-using-avaudioplayer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize your audio file in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`
and play it in `applicationWillResignActive`.