# How to play audio when app is in background?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, avaudioplayer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Play Audio in background in IPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538324/how-to-play-audio-in-background-in-iphone)

I want to play audio when app is in background at particular time(which i have set).Its Working fine but for first  time AVAudioplayer is not enabled when app is in back ground.Its working fine from the the second time.For first time app must be in foreground.How to play for first time itself if app is in background?

Comment: @Parth Bhatt: Please refrain from editing duplicate links into questions after voting to close. The system already generates a comment with a link on your behalf. If a question is closed as a duplicate, the system will convert the comment into an edit automatically. Having the link there if it's not otherwise useful will only mislead others.

Comment: @BoltClock:  Ok fine. I thought it has to be done manually.

Answer (score -1):

Refer apple's documentation on this... pretty neatly explained.. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html