# I want to continue to play music even if after press button HOME in iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, home-button

I want to continue to play music even if after user presses button HOME on the iPhone. Can you help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619794/play-music-in-background-in-iphone-using-avaudioplayer

Comment: I read it. But I need a specific tutorial because I'm beginner! hic...

Answer (score 1):

refer a [this site](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_background-audio/). You'll be very helpful. Good luck