# Spotify playbackmanager volume is very low

Tags: ios, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I am developing one iOS app which is using the Spotify API . I have an issue regarding the SPPlaybackManager volume. The sound is very low when I am playing the Spotify song. Could any one please tell me how to increase the sound.(In original Spotify iOS app they are accessing the iPhone device sound i.e if you increase the slider value system volume also increasing)

```
[self.playbackManager setVolume:self.volumeSlider.value];
```

Comment: Are you setting an AVAudioSession category? Are you playing non-spotify audio that is the right volume?

Comment: I am playing the Spotify audio . I am not setting AVAudioSession . Can I use AVAudioSession on Spotify songs

Comment: Try setting AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback like in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7619816/22147

Answer (score 0):

`SPPlaybackManager`'s volume is relative to the iOS device's media playback volume, so if that's low your playback will be low as well. For a typical playback app, you'd tend to leave this property at `1.0` and adjust the system's volume instead.

Comment: I agree with you @iKenndac but When I set volume to playbackmanager it is not increasing the system volume

Comment: It's not supposed to. You need to set the system volume yourself.