# AVFoundation playing audio in background/on lock screen in Swift

Tags: swift, ios8, avfoundation

I'm trying to find a way with AVFoundation to play audio when the user is on the lock screen or if they lock the app in the middle of using my app

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {
    var avPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
    var error: NSError?

... other stuff ... 

    func playChime(fileName: String) -> Void {
        let fileURL: NSURL! = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(fileName, withExtension: "wav")
        self.avPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: fileURL, error: nil)
        self.avPlayer?.play()
    }
... other stuff ... 
}
```

What needs to be added to this to ensure sounds play when the user is on the lock screen as well?

Comment: Similar case but in Objective-C: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619794/play-music-in-the-background-using-avaudioplayer

Answer (score 5):

To continue playing audio in the background when the device is locked or on the home screen (on Xcode 6.3):

Add to your ViewController:

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
```

Then in your Info.plist, add a new entry for UIBackgroundModes and set it to audio. Xcode will automatically fill it out as 'Require background modes' and 'App plays audio or streams audio/video using Airplay'