# Audio in Background not working on Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, audio, audiokit

Audio in Background works perfectly on devices but not on Simulators (different machines) with same iOS version (11.4) as working devices.

Setup:

```
 AKSettings.playbackWhileMuted = true
 do { try AudioKit.start() } ...
```

Info.plist:

Required background modes -> App plays audio or streams audio/video using AirPlay

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that the simulators basically don't work with background mode.   Cf:

[Play music in the background using AVAudioplayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619794/play-music-in-the-background-using-avaudioplayer)

[How to continue audio playback in background mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31602342/how-to-continue-audio-playback-in-background-mode?rq=1)