# Override silent switch and play audio during notifcation -- like Tile

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

Long story short, I am currently using Bluetooth LE Beacons (iBeacon) to determine if something is in range or not (using `didEnterRegion`/`didExitRegion`)

Currently, when those methods get called while the app is backgrounding, I send a local notification using the `UserNotification` framework. I have been requested to also play an alert overriding the silent switch when `didExitRegion` is called, similar to how Tile plays sends a notification with audio when the button is played.

If anyone knows how tile works or another way to accomplish this that would be great.

So far, I have attempted to call `play()` on an `AVAudioPlayer` with the audio loaded, however `play()` just returns false from the background. I have also Enabled the Audio backgrounding mode to no avail

Comment: did you set `AVAudioSession` to active

Comment: did you check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7619816/6689101)

Comment: I did set audio session to active

Comment: And the only thing I didn’t do was set beginRevieveingRemoteControlEvents, so I doubt that’ll do anything/won’t do what I want