# iOS 5 background playback error

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avqueueplayer

I am using **AVQueuePlayer** for playing media from internet. I set proper **AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback**, added **UIBackgroundModes** **audio** and I used **UIBackgroundTask** for making playback continue working in background (start background task after track has ended and end it upon next track is ready to play).
And everything works, both active and background mode.
But sometimes playback in background stops for no reason.
And everything I have is a message in console:

**Jun  1 13:36:01 unknown mediaserverd[646] : 13:36:01.921 <0x5063000> AudioQueue: Error -12985 from AudioSessionSetClientPlayState(1215)**

So what does it mean?

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349173/audioqueuestart-fail-12985

Comment: it is a bit different problem, because i use AVQueuePlayer and not AudioQueue. But this gave me fresh information to look at. Thanks.